# iOS - Facebook Login Check Login Status

Tags: ios, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to implement Facebook login for my app. I have it working so that if the app opens up to the login view controller (with a `FBLoginView`) then the user can log in and I receive the delegate methods `-loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:` and `- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:`

I want to create a smoother UI for opening the app. I don't want it to show the `FBLoginView` every time at the start unless the user needs to log in. What I'm doing is initially opening up to a viewController that just displays the launchImage and then checks the login status of the user. If a user is already logged in, then it segues to the main part of the app; otherwise, it segues to the login view controller. The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to check login status other than the delegate methods of the `FBLoginView`. I see the FB javascript SDK has a method `FB.getLoginStatus()`. Is there anything like that for iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FBLoginView` maintains the session in FBSession.activeSession, and once the user has logged in once, it also caches the credentials in the KeyChain. So what you can do is:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO];
if ([[FBSession activeSession] isOpen]) {
  // do regular stuff
} else {
  // segue to loginView
}
```

This will attempt to create an open session without any user interaction (i.e. from a cached token). If the session is open, then you can stay in your current viewController, otherwise segue to the loginView.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSession/#openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI: